# SQL Job ignores for loop in batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, for-loop, ssms, sql-job

We have billing statements on a server. They are organized into folders by year, and then in that folder into more folders by month. I'm trying to create a SQL Job to go to the statements folder, open the folder for the year of the previous month (as this is run on the first of each month), loop through to find the newest folder, go in there, find the newest item in that folder, create a "Completed" folder, and move the newest item to that folder.

```
REM ------------------------------------
REM Get year and month of previous month
REM ------------------------------------
SET month=%DATE:~4,2%
if "%month:~0,1%"=="0" (set month=%month:~1%)
set /a prevmonth=%month% - 1
set yearprevmo=%DATE:~10,4%
if %prevmonth% equ 0 set /a yearprevmo=%yearprevmo%-1 & set prevmonth=12
pushd \\SERVER\Statements
cd %yearprevmo%
REM ------------------------------------
REM Get most newly created folder
REM ------------------------------------
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /t:c /od') DO SET newestfolder=%%i
cd %newestfolder%
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /a-d /t:c /od') DO SET zipname=%%i
mkdir Completed
move %zipname% Completed
```

When I run this batch file myself, it runs fine and does everything I expect it to do. When I create a SQL Job to run this batch file, point it at the correct file, and make sure the SQL account has all the correct permissions, it correctly runs everything except for the for loops.

Running it as is, it opens the server fine, navigates to the correct year folder, but then does not change to the month folder, and creates the Completed folder where it currently is. (it creates \server\Statements\2019\Completed rather than \server\Statements\2019\May\Completed).

If I hard code the newest month, it correctly navigates to that folder, but then doesn't loop through to find the newest item in there. It still creates the Completed folder, but doesn't move the item into it. If I hard code the item name, it navigates fine and moves everything where it needs to go.

Clearly the for loop is the issue here, but I can't find any information about why a SQL job would ignore a for loop, or any errors it might cause while still allowing it to complete subsequent commands.

Comment: I would suggest you use this to get the two variables with your required month and year values, `@For /F Tokens^=1* %%A In ('PowerShell -NoP "(Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString('yyy M')"')Do @Set /A YearOfLastMonth=%%A,LastMonth=%%B`. That should work on any Windows OS with [tag:powershell] installed regardless of the locale or user settings.

Comment: @Compo, unfortunately I just used "May" as an example. The folder titles for each month are a little more complicated and since they are created manually by someone else, not consistently in the exact same format always (sometimes spaces are replaced by dashes, sometimes neither are used, etc) and so grabbing the most newly created folder is the only way we've been able to make sure the correct folder is looked at.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, all I have done is provide you with an alternative way of determining the year e.g. `2019`, and month, i.e. `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `10`, `11` or `12`, instead of the `5` lines you used. Your code doesn't attempt to attribute `May` to anything, although the code above could be modified to determine that too, example: `@For /F Tokens^=1* %%A In ('PowerShell -NoP "(Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString('y')"')Do @Set "DateString=%%B\%%A"`.

Comment: I used May in my example of a file path. Like I said in my comment though, while this might be useful for year, the month folders are in the format "05-MAY-19", but the person who creates the folders does not name them consistently enough, so it could be "05 MAY 19" or "05 - MAY-19" or even "05-MAT-18". They create the folders without really paying attention, so looping through to find the newest one is the best way to find what I need.

Either way, again the issue is that loops aren't working at all, and I don't know why.

Comment: Please read the following and tell me what I have gotten wrong! The first `8` lines of your provided code, determine todays year and month, then adjust them to provide the year and month as it was 1 month ago. So running it today on exactly the same unmodified system, it would return line `4`:`%month%=06`, line `5`:`%month%=6`, line `6`:`%prevmonth%=5`, line `7`:`%yearprevmo%=2019` line `8`:`no changes`. So, despite the fact that you never used `%month%` or `%prevmonth%` in your code, instead of doing all of that I offered a single line to set `%YearOfLastMonth%`=`2019` and `%LastMonth%`=`5`.

Comment: Ahhh, fair enough, my bad. That part is working well enough that it just didn't even register in my brain as being relevant to the question.